# Access denied to VisualStudio_10 entries in windows7 registry

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, permissions, registry

When I try to access *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cs.10* or any other entry of VisualStudio that ends with 10 I get the following error ***VisualStudio.cs.10.0 cannot be opened. An error is preventing this key from being opened. Details: Access is denied.***

What can be the problem?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, where all my VS2010-entries have access denied (I suspect that it happened after installing VS2010 SP1, but that is just a guess). Did you make any progress on this or find some way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you start your Visual Studio "As Administrator..."?
**EDIT:**
See my comment below...
Check the owner of the registry entry.

Comment: Yes I did, but how this refer to my question? When I click on **entry** in **registry**(regedit) I get this error

Comment: Well then I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to manipulate the registry with some code. Sorry... In your case you could check who the owner of the registry entries you want to manipulate is. Could be "Trusted Installer" then you have to change it to "Administrator" (for example).

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't let me to access this entry. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried it with the following key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cs.10.0 and I could change e.g. AlwaysShowExt from 1 to 0 and vice versa without a problem. Did you also start regedit "As Administrator..."?